# Unable to catch an event for changing the permission externally

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-permissions

Can anybody tell which method calls, When I change permission of app from SETTINGS page ,When app is in minimized state.?

App Code :https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxK5c-Q5uNaPOWJycFVtaThxWmc/view?usp=sharing
1)App asked for camera permssion

2)User Granted

3)App  minimized

4)Go to setting -->apps -->revoke camera permission Now i need to know which method calls in activity or how to handle the recreation of activity.

> NOTE :

Now What happened Presently is App getting Recreating again ,can anybody tell how to stop it.?

Comment: use OnRestartMethod of Activity. check permission  there

Comment: Check permission on OnResume()

Comment: @DivyeshPatel Thank you for response but as app getting recreating that means it is calling the destroy method ..But when i open it from the minimize state it is working like hell.

Comment: check the permission each time you need to the action which needs the permission, in that way no exception will be thrown if the user changed the permission from the settings of the app while the app is opened